# Is there a YSlow-like tool for IE7?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-7

I love [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)/[Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html?from=getfirefox), but I've hit a situation where I want to profile an HTTPS site, that doesn't physically work outside of IE6/7 (e.g. no IE8, no Firefox, no Chrome)

Fixing the site to work in all browsers is officially Step #1, but to do some analysis and benchmark the existing site (which will help in reporting overall goal achievement) I really need to be able to profile the existing site.

In particular the info I'm looking for is:

1. Overall page speed
2. Static content (what images, css, js files) are cached, minimized, gzipped
3. Counts/locations of slow CSS (e.g. usage of CSS Expressions)
4. Cookie info
5. Image sizes
6. Duplicate scripts/css
7. File sizes
   etc.

Without a specific do-all tool, are there specific tools that will help me solve part(s) of the puzzle.

e.g.

- I have [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) set up... which will give me HTTP(S) sessions, headers, requests, filesizes, gzipping, etc.
- I have a bookmarklet or two that will tally up duplicate scripts/css
- I have the [IE7 developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) installed so that I can view the HTML and inspect things

Using the above I can extract most of the info and then tally up my own "score"/checklist of things that need attention however it is a fair amount of work. :-(

Does anyone have some better tools for this?
**Is there a YSlow-like tool for IE7??**

Comment: There would be, but it would always just say stop using IE7  =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just came accross MSFAST, a new addon from MySpace Performance team
http://msfast.myspace.com/

It does performance analysis and there is a YSLOW quotation system.

Comment: Thanks Marin! - that is almost exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

## You Can Run Yslow In Internet Explorer

All You Need To Do Is:

1. Click [Here](http://yslow.org/mobile/) (Using IE)
2. Scroll Down To 'Desktop Bookmarklet Installation Instructions'
3. Right Click The Blue Rectangle Reading 'YSlow' & Then Add To Favourites

Now You Have YSlow In Your Favourites, Go To The Webpage You Want To Test &

Click YSlow From Your Favourites Menu To Run The Test.

***UPDATE: The YSLOW Bookmarklet has not been updated by the YSLOW team and as of June 2016 does not work in IE11***

Comment: This is actually a really nice option... and works for mobile too!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [dynaTrace AJAX](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/). Works with IE and should give you most of the info you're wanting.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but Firebug Lite can run on IE .. ?

Comment: Firebug Lite is quite nice, but the YSlow plugin (and Google's page speed plugin) do not transfer over to the Firebug Lite Bookmarklet. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well I am afraid there is none.However you can use [HTTP](http://www.httpwatch.com/download/) Watch to profile.Just give a look & see if it helps.Good Luck

Comment: looks good, I'll try it out and see if it works as advertised ;-)

Comment: hmmm, it does give some nice timings and basic HTTP header info... unfortunately you need to buy the full version to get the details. :-(

Comment: But your requirement will be fulfilled with the basic version.Why do you need the full version?

Answer (score 0):

Charles Web Proxy has a yslow like feature built in. It works with IE. It is shareware and costs $50 to purchase.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

I had similar question and this is the best thing that I found for IE. Hope this helps!